# Multiplicación de tablas relacionadas

Tags: django, djangorestframework

Quisiera saber como lograr esto con Django ORM

```
select
   SUM(ve.cantidad * vop.precio) 
from
   ventas_online_ventas ve 
   inner join
      ventas_online_productoventa vop 
      on vop.id = ve.producto_id;
```

Este es el modelo que uso para crear las tablas, la información de los pedidos la recivo por correo por lo que estoy un poco atado en la creacion de estos modelos

**Tabla para guardar los tipos de productos que se ofertan**

```py
class ProductoVenta(models.Model):
    producto = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Producto'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Productos'
        ordering = ['producto']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.producto
```

**Las ordenes de venta donde estan todos los datos de el comprador y el destinatario**

```py
class OrdenVenta(models.Model):
    pedido = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    recogida = models.ForeignKey(Recogida, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    comprador = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    destinatario = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    provincia = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    fecha = models.DateField()
    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadoVenta, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Orden de Venta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ordenes de Ventas'

        ordering = ['pedido']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pedido
```

**Aquí guardo las ventas de cada producto por ordenes para pder hacer un analisis detallado de la tendencia de los productos**

```py
class Ventas(models.Model):
    orden = models.ForeignKey(OrdenVenta, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(ProductoVenta, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Venta'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ventas'
        ordering = ['orden']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.orden.pedido

    def importe(self):
        return self.producto.precio * self.cantidad
```

Comment: Que has intentado hasta ahora para pasar eso a django?

Comment: Si muestrar el código de los models, puede ayudar. Si explicas un poco lo que quieres que haga el código también. Un saludo.

Comment: Tengo tres tablas relacionadas (ordenes de venta, productos y ventas), en la primera guardo todo lo relacionado con los datos del comprador y el resector, en la segunda los tipos de productos y sus precios y la tercera la cantidad de productos vendidos de en cada orden, por lo que la tabla ventas tiene relaciónes de uno a mucho con las otras dos tablas. Lo que necesito es obtener la venta total multiplicacndo la cantidad de productos vendidos por su precio. Grasias